# Android development in IntelliJ IDEA causes computer to freeze

Tags: android, crash, intellij-idea, usb

I am using IntelliJ IDEA (10.5) for Android development with latest Google USB Driver (version 4) for debugging. After some time of development in IntelliJ IDEA when Android device (Nexus One) is connected via USB, the computer (with Windows 7, 32 bit) freezes. No blue screen just freeze. Everything is visible but screen is not updating. I have to restart the computer.

Is anyone experiencing similar issues? Any solutions?

Comment: Never had such problem, looks like driver/hardware issue to me.

Comment: Doesn't seem anything related to IntelliJ. Does it happen each time you do this ? Try connecting the phone when IntelliJ is not running..

Comment: Eclipse was working OK, it appeared after I started using IntelliJ IDEA (because of better Scala support). Maybe IntelliJ is using the driver differently than Eclipse.

Comment: @advantej It appears after some time (e.g. hours) of debugging and development.

Comment: May be the driver is buggy. I use IntelliJ but don't use it to deploy apps. I prefer command line.

Comment: I am deploying via Ant, but it usually freezes during writing a code (not during deploying nor debugging).

Comment: How much ram in the computer? Try playing a 3d game, does that also crash your computer? If so, hardware issue.

Comment: I am not experiencing similar problems with other SW, such as Visual Studio, SharpDevelop, Eclipse or NetBeans. And I have enough free memory.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not sure how to comment on your original post (the field is not displayed).

I'm experiencing the same issue and I'd love to determine a solution.  It's very annoying!

I use Eclipse (Windows 7 64-bit) with a Nexus One (2.2) and my PC will randomly, completely freeze.  The mouse pointer locks up, Caps Lock button (and others) don't toggle, touch pad doesn't react, etc.  No blue screen and nothing is ever written to the system's event log.  I have to physically shut down the machine and restart it each time.

At first, it happened in the same manner for me -- developing within Eclipse.  I noticed it didn't happen on compile or debug launch, more during development (again, randomly).  Then I noticed it started happening when Eclipse wasn't open at all.  That's when I started to suspect a driver or similar issue.  But I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further from here.

If anyone has ANY insight into this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Incorrectly reported N1 version as 2.1 -- corrected to 2.2

Comment: Yes, you have same symptoms as me. What is your PC manufacturer, GPU manufacturer and what antivirus software are you using?

Comment: PC is a Gateway NV59.  Not sure if I have a dedicated GPU (it's a laptop), but Device Manager says Intel HD Graphics.  Antivirus is Norton Internet Security 2011.

Comment: That's completely different what I have. But still, try to uninstall Norton and install e.g. Microsoft Security Essentials and let me know if it helps. I had Avast and after uninstalling Avast and installing MSE the freezing does not appear so frequently.

Comment: I've never had any other issues with my antivirus/firewall software, so I'm pretty convinced it's not that.

I've tracked it down to only happening when the device is connected via USB (with or without Eclipse running) so I think its related to the driver, device, etc.  I'm just not sure how to further troubleshoot that particular path.

One thing I just thought of as I'm typing this is to use a different USB cable.  At least, I can try eliminating that as a culprit.

If anyone has any ideas on how to troubleshoot the driver or device, I'd appreciate it.  (Note: My device is not rooted.)

Comment: Now, it is happening to me also with disconnected devices.

Comment: I haven't experienced that scenario (yet).  My device has been connected each time it has frozen on me.  But, I'll try leaving it disconnected and let my laptop run overnight to test if it freezes by itself by morning.

Comment: My laptop ran perfectly fine overnight and was ready for me in the morning.  No alerts, sluggishness, etc.  It even ran a full virus scan while I was away.  With my Nexus One connected, it would've frozen in just a third of that time.  I'm now pretty confident that the issue is related to the USB cable, the driver, or the device.  Next, I'll try switching to a different USB cable.  At the very least, I'll be able to disprove it's a problem with the cable.

Comment: Ok, let we know if you problem get fixed using different USB cable.

Comment: My apologies for the delay.  I was distracted by other projects.  But, that gave me the chance to completely confirm that things run smoothly when the device is not plugged in.  Three weeks, no freezes, no symptoms at all.  Today, I connected the device using the original stock cable and my computer froze within an hour.  Eclipse was running, but I don't think that makes a difference.  I'm going to try letting the computer run without Eclipse running.  If it freezes again, it's not the USB cable.

Comment: I had an interesting turn of events this morning!  As I mentioned in my last comment, I let my laptop run overnight _without_ Eclipse running.  I fully expected to wake up to a frozen computer this morning, but to my surprise, it was still running.  Frustrated, because that contradicted the USB cable tests, I started to think about Eclipse again.  Why would that make a difference?  And why would you be having a problem if you use a different IDE?  What did they have in common?  Then it hit me -- they both need ADB to communicate with the devices!  (continued below...)

Comment: (continued...) I did a quick search for "adb freezes computer" and bingo! The very first link was a Google bug report describing _exactly_ what we've been experiencing. I think we may have found our smoking gun. Now, the next questions are (1) why is it happening? and (2) how can we fix or work around it?  (continued below...)

Comment: (continued...) Link to Google bug report: [http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24171](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24171) ... Link to a similar Stack Overflow issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076440/over-populating-logcat-causes-windows-to-freeze-until-hard-reboot-is-performed/9875171#9875171](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076440/over-populating-logcat-causes-windows-to-freeze-until-hard-reboot-is-performed/9875171#9875171)

Comment: +1 Thx for the links. It seems to me that the bug is also somewhere in Win7 (sort of kernel drivers deadlock). Since on some computers it is also happening with other software -- no adb, no Android connected. And nearly always it helps to stop the antivirus realtime protection (tested with Avast and Microsoft Security Essentials). -- It seems to me that there are multiple bugs in kernel drivers that collides with each other.

Comment: Sure thing!  I'm hoping others find these links and offer their experiences, too.  Adding to (and "starring") the Google bug report will also be very helpful!  The more visible it is, the more likely it is to get fixed.

Comment: As for your observation, I don't think it's isolated to just Win 7.  The Google bug report shows at least one person who is running Win XP.  Also, the Stack Overflow link was mainly for cross-reference.  It seems to have a collection of other problems mixed within it, so I'm not sure it matches our issue 100%.

Comment: ADB makes sense because that process doesn't load until the Android tools load.  And if you forget to kill the ADB process, it makes it seem that the USB connection is what freezes your system.  But, it's simply the fact that ADB was still running in the background.  If you boot fresh, don't load your IDE, and connect your device, I'm willing to bet you'll never experience a freeze.

Comment: The other computer does not have adb at all.

Comment: Interesting.  How does it connect to the device?

Comment: The machine is not used for Android development, but still have this issue with other software (e.g. LINQPad).

Comment: At the risk of this happening again 5 seconds after I post this...  ;)

I believe the latest SDK update (r17) fixed my issue.  Nothing granular is listed within the changelog, but there may have been some underlying changes that corrected what was happening.

After 4 days of working with Eclipse, ADB, debugging, and even leaving my laptop on overnight to run other tasks (with Eclipse and ADB still running), I haven't seen one system freeze.

Comment: You are lucky:) I've just installed new IntellJ Idea 11.1 and computer froze on the first start of Idea (from the installer). (Even if the realtime antivirus protection was turned off.) After restart the installation was corrupted and I had to uninstall it and install it again. In my case, I suspect also some other drivers -- maybe related to disk I/O.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I meant that I updated the Android SDK (and all Android-related updates). Sorry to hear about your IntelliJ issue. I hope you're able to find a solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

Idea is known to have long GC pauses sometimes - it may freeze completely for some time. And it takes even longer if it goes into swap - in this case, whole system may become unresponsive. See this [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-4063) and [discussion in forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/291169).

So, if it is indeed your case, try using statically-compiled version from [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jetgallery.html) - it's proven to work faster.

Comment: It freezes whole OS not just that app and it never resumes. (Neither mouse cursor moves.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like OS/Hardware problem

Comment: Yes, I am suspecting IntelliJ IDEA <-> Android device driver. Maybe IntelliJ IDEA is using the driver in some other way than Eclipse.