# Overpopulating Logcat causes Windows to freeze, until a hard reboot is performed

Tags: android, adt, logcat

The title speaks for itself, but I would add some pointers I've noticed along the way.

I would like anyone who also experiences the end result while developing for Android to try to reproduce this and see if this scenario is really the case.

The crash happens when Logcat is overpopulated. By overpopulated I mean that from a point in time, if you would leave a device connected in debug mode for a while, and you would look at the Logcat view, it would display only the new 'delta' lines added to the log in the past short interval of about two seconds.

If you would pay attention, while the Logcat is overpopulated, the device which is been debugged, responds slowly to user interaction (this can be your indication, that the Logcat is overpopulated while testing your application), and perform other actions ridiculously slow.

If you would leave the device connected and more logs would be added, there is a short interval 5-10 seconds, where [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) starts to behave weird, and after that, there is nothing you can do, Windows 7 freezes and only hard reboot allows you to get back to work.

I can reproduce this every time, if I would just leave a device connected in debug mode with an application running.

I've Googled this and came up with nothing. I assume that if me and my colleagues encounter this (we have the same Eclipse setup), then other should also experience this, so before posting a bug, I would like to confirm this...

Details:

- Windows 7
- Eclipse 3.6
- [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Android_Development_Tools) 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271 (latest for today)

Comment: I see this too. Anyone figure anything out? I tried "android developer"'s workaround but didn't help me.

Comment: I have ADT 16 installed... and I've become so good at recognizing the signs the computer makes before it crashes, that I manage sometimes to disconnect my device on time, to clear the log... :)

Comment: * This never happens again on my newer setup!!!
* Download the Android Eclipse bundle, and use only it, not a clean Eclipse and install Android plugin!!
* Upgrade to windows 8!
* I use same code on 3 computers and all fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem here.  I've been troubleshooting this for months!  Mostly because it's been extremely difficult to find anyone with the same issue.  (I was actually linked *to* this post *from* the bug report that Android Developer provided.)

I've been working with someone on a similar Stack Overflow issue.  He thought the problem was his IDE until I reported that I was experiencing the same issue, but with a different IDE.  Together, we've been able to whittle the problem down to either the device itself or the drivers.  We recently just excluded the USB cables as the culprit.

However, the problems reported in the Google bug report are *exactly* what we've been experiencing.  It makes sense that **ADB might be where the problem ultimately lies**.

Hopefully, this post will help create some search-friendly connections between the other posts.

---

**Other Stack Overflow post mentioned above** -- [Android development in IntelliJ IDEA causes computer to freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265519/android-development-in-intellij-idea-causes-computer-to-freeze/9440450#comment12062275_9440450)

**Google bug report, Issue #24171 (originally posted by Android Developer)** -- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24171

Comment: At work I've started to work with a new HTC device, and it now it crashes every single time... and it does not twitch before crashing :( I think the only thing I didn't mention, is that I use a Dell Laptop at work... and recently I've updated to ADT 17. Today, I can say for sure, that if I disconnect and reconnect the device every 3-5 minutes, I prevent the crash! but it is annoying as hell during debugging!!!

Comment: And here is another though... how do you watch your log? I know some devices produce more logs then others, for whatever reason, most of it is verbose, so perhaps if you watch the log with verbose filter you could estimate the log messages count, because the counter there is off.

Comment: I've also tried disconnecting and reconnecting the device (in the past) but I had no luck with that.  It still froze.  And when it freezes, I get no warning signs.  No slowdowns, etc.  It just suddenly freezes and I'm forced to reboot.

Comment: Which computer and which device?

Comment: Gateway NV59, Win 7 Home Premium 64-bit, Nexus One

Comment: So it is a laptop too... interesting, this is the first common I found... both are laptops... is there any one using a stationary computer that experience this?

Comment: Check out the Google bug report and post something there if you feel it fits.  That's the most central point in terms of visibility (and an eventual fix).  I saw at least three different flavors of OS, but not sure about machine configurations.

Comment: At the risk of this happening again 5 seconds after I post this...  ;)

I believe the latest SDK update (r17) fixed my issue.  Nothing granular is listed within the changelog, but there may have been some underlying changes that corrected what was happening.

After 4 days of working with Eclipse, ADB, debugging, and even leaving my laptop on overnight to run other tasks (with Eclipse and ADB still running), I haven't seen one system freeze.

Comment: I have an HTC device in my hands now, which crashes my work Laptop computer constantly... regardless of the ADT version 16/17, I'm toying with the thought of letting it crash my private home computer... to see if perhaps it is device related!

Comment: I can say now, with a bit more confidence that the problem is PC related, my work LapTop crashes in a few minutes if my HTC is connected to it, and same HTC, connected to my home LapTop does not crash... and it has been connected for hours now... perhaps the problem is related to the application been debugged? (I'm working on two different projects!)

Comment: And I've noticed something now... the device goes offline every once in a while on my home computer, while at my work computer, I've never experienced the devices go offline... how about you?

Comment: When you say offline, are you referring to wifi?  If so, yes, I've seen that occasionally, but I don't know when it began or how it happens.  It just does and turning off wifi and turning it back on always fixes it.  The wifi issue and the ADB one seemed unrelated since they didn't happen at the same time, but who knows.  I just thought maybe it was a bug with the Nexus One.

Comment: I was referring to the devices view in Eclipse... the device sometimes goes 'offline'... note that when all is ok and you can debug, it is 'online'.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now.  I never experienced that particular symptom.

Comment: I've added an answer... please take a look

Comment: (Not sure why,  but I can't comment underneath that answer.)  Sorry, but that's not the case for me.  I'm using the stock power adapter.  Keep an eye on the Google Bug Report (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24171).  A few more people have commented on it since I last posted here.  We've narrowed the problem down to be something wrong with the USB port itself.  It seems when each of us switched to a different port, the problem went away.  I haven't had a freeze in a while  Now the questions are: how can we predict that it's going to happen, and how can we fix the port issue?

Answer (score 3):

I also have a similar problem. Sometimes, the Windows OS completely freeze when an Android device is connected.

I'm not sure why it happens, but I think that it only occurs when the [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)) is active.

Here's a bug report I've found recently about this:
*[adb causes whole Windows operating system to freeze randomly](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36938544)*

After using a USB from the back, and installing [Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8), the problem doesn't occur any more.

However, it's Windows 8, and I wish I used [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7). For some reason, Microsoft didn't provide a way to go back...

Comment: which one? i can't see anything that helps with it. anyway , i've "solved" it by installing windows 8 .

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your Eclipse Android Settings for the maximum amount of logcat messages in the buffer to a lower value.
This should help

Comment: This actually causes the crash faster!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to jump to conclusions, but I think I've found the real issue which causes this halt...

I'm going to make some assumptions, and if one of these does not fit your scenario, let me know:

**Assumptions:**

1. This only happens on a chargeable computer... Be very very sure **before dismissing** this assumption.
2. This happens when a *laptop* is connected to the adapter, and is being charged.

**Cause:**

- This happens when you use a custom adapter, and not one that 100% fit your computer.

According to my experience, once I've used my home adapter on my work computer, the crash reoccurred over, and over, and over... drove me nuts... and when I got back to work, and used the proper adapter, the issue vanished!

Same with my home computer, and work adapter.

Lend me your thoughts...

Comment: Windows crashes randomly when Eclipse with ADT are running on a stationary PC in my case.

Comment: there goes that theory... :(

Comment: What is "the adapter"? A USB cable? A power brick (for charging)? [Power adapter/AC adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_adapter#Laptop_charger)?